# Value for Pattern Attribute for Input Field like words "Kim", "Kim Sun", "Kim 2" etc

Tags: regex, validation, input

Words start with minimum 3 letters and then may be a white space and numbers, say "Kim", "Kim Sun", "Kim 2" etc. In this case, what should be the value for pattern attribute for html input field?

I have a working regex for php for the same purpose `"/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/i"`. I tried from this as :

`<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" title="Must type a name starting with letters, but then numbers and white space allowed" required="required" aria-required="true" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}[a-zA-Z0-9 ]" spellcheck="false" size="15">`

But the pattern attribute is not working.

Comment: "But it is not working" - what isn't working?

Comment: @James Donnelly, sorry for not to clear the question. Now I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is you forgot the `+` at the end.

Try: `[a-zA-Z]{3,}[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+`